# Firebase Cloud Messing possible bug?

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send a push notification through FCM, but the response sent to the phone is weird and does not include aps.

I send:

```
{ "notification" : {
  "title" : "this is title",
  "body" : "this is body",
  "sound" : "defadult"
},
"data": {
"score": "5x1",
"time": "15:10"
},
"time_to_live" : 3000,
"priority" : "high",
"content_available": true,
"to" : "<fcm access token>"
}
```

and I get the following on the phone:

```
%@ [notification: {
body = "this is body";
e = 1;
sound = default;
sound2 = defadult;
title = "this is title";
}, collapse_key: <bundle-url>, score: 5x1, time: 15:10, from: 844316448558]
```

This had been working for a while but suddenly broke. Does anyone else experience this?

Comment: Is that still an issue? A couple days ago there seemed to be an issue affecting APNs sandbox, but it is now fixed.

Comment: yes, this is still happening.

Comment: What are you using to send the notification?

Comment: 1. postman to send a POST request to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send, 2. my server is on Google App Engine and it sends a request similar to the postman, 3. Firebase console, where you can send a mass push notification.

Comment: I've just ran the exact same request (copied your body from the question) in postman and got 2016-07-22 09:18:09.186 FCM[1196:276820] {
    aps =     {
        alert =         {
            body = "this is body";
            title = "this is title";
        };
        "content-available" = 1;
        sound = defadult;
    };
    "gcm.message_id" = "0:1469204289471277%57c47c4857c47c48";
    score = 5x1;
    time = "15:10";
}

Comment: Have you uninstalled and reinstalled the app, the issue I mentioned in the first comment is related to the generation of an APNs token. Uninstalling the app and reinstalling it would ensure that the new InstanceID token is correctly associated with the APNs token. If the IID token you are using now is not associated with an APNs token this could be the reason you are seeing the response in this format.

Comment: Okay, I will try it and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: deleted the app, but I got same thing back. I notice in your request's response "gcm.message_id". Are you using FCM or GCM?

Comment: I'm using FCM, the gcm.message_id field is used for both FCM and GCM. Are you using the latest version of the Firebase Messaging Pod 1.1.0? Also there are some unexpected fields in your response, given your request. Where are the fields 'e', 'sound2' and 'collapse_key' coming from? Are you sure the request you define in the question is generating the response here?

Comment: i'm not sure about 'collapse_key' as I might have seen it before, but the 'e' and 'sound2' are the weird ones that show up with the new push notifications. and 'aps' is missing, which is why the notifications don't work outside of the app. I am on the latest FCM pod 1.1.0. I copy pasted that request from postman. that exact thing does not work. Of course, I replace access token with 'FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()'

Comment: I just found the problem! I had recently moved "FIRApp.configure()" to init() of AppDelegate rather than usual "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" I don't know why that makes a difference on push notification, but I just put it back in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" and it works! thanks for the help!!

Comment: Glad you got things working, FIRApp.configure() may be expecting things that were not available in init() so I'd be careful when moving that around.